# Change button action in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change button action/change button in Firefox PDF web viewer. Is it posible?
Problem step by step:

1.I've got pdf on my website added by:

```
<div>
    <object id="testpdf" data="pdfFile.pdf" type="application/pdf" height="800px" width="100%">
       <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </object>
</div>
```

It is loading fine in firefox pdf web viewer.

2. When it is loaded I'd like to change print button in it - remove standard print action and add my action (run "myProtocol:///pdfFile.pdf" or start process "AcroRdr32 /p pdfFile.pdf" - to run printing by Adobe Reader or start printing by Adobe Reader in any other way (except download it and run printing manually)).

Is it possible to do? Demo of firefox web viewer is in https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**
I've tried to do it by:

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    if (("testpdf").readyState === 'complete') {
        document.getElementById("print").outerHTML = '<button onclick="location.href=\'icprint://C:/pdfFile.pdf\'" id="print" class="toolbarButton print hiddenMediumView" title="Drukowanie"><span class="print_label">Drukuj</span></button>';
    };
};
```

But it's not working, the deeper id, that I've accessed is #testpdf

Comment: The first thing I noticed, is that `("testpdf")`should be $('#testpdf'). The second thing: Is readystate possible for an object?

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried this, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, I found the print-Button in the Firefox-Inspector (F12).
[image: Firefox-Inspector shows print button]

You can change the title and the onClick of the button like that:

```
const ele = document.getElementById('print');
ele.title = 'Drukowanie';
ele.onclick = function() { window.location.href='icprint://C:/pdfFile.pdf'; }
```

Can you access C:?

=> Something like that, if you use jquery (I have not tested it):

```
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    if ($('#testpdf').readyState === 'complete') {
        const ele = document.getElementById('print');
        ele.title = 'Drukowanie';
        ele.onclick = function() { window.location.href='icprint://C:/pdfFile.pdf'; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but this also not working for me.